# How to check for a database state before saving new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a more ruby idiomatic way to handle checking if database has 5 records other then to use an if statement, should this be done in a filter or any type of validation?

```
saved_count = Model.where(is_active: true).count
if saved_count == MAX_SAVED
  return {error: 'Cannot save more than 5 records'}
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use validation:

```
class Model
  # I would create a scope to use it in validation
  # scope :active, -> { where(is_active: true) }

  validate :max_count

  private

  def max_count
    errors.add(:base, 'Cannot save more than 5 records') if self.class.active.count == 5
  end
end
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use "on: :create". What if there is 5 active and 1 inactive and the inactive is updated as active?

Comment: so I have something like validates :name, presence: true, [I cant just append :max_count to this]

Comment: @eugenekgn no, there is no inbuilt `amount` validation in Rails yet, so it can be achieved with custom validation (using `validate`)

Comment: so this would be wrong validate: name, allow_blaknk: false, max_count?

Comment: this just won't work but after all you can just try it out :)

Comment: so I need to separate validate declarations in my model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101523/discussion-between-eugenekgn-and-andrey-deineko).

Comment: You are correct, you'd pretty much need to add what I showed in my answer so that any object edited or created there is a validation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101526/discussion-between-eugenekgn-and-andrey-deineko).