# Check object's errors on model.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have the following validation run on `Model.save` action:

```
  def max_count
    errors.add(:base, 'Cannot save more than 5 records') if self.class.active.count == 5
  end
```

Why is my `Model.errors` object `nil` upon save?

This post can be used as a reference [How to check for a database state before saving new records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977849/how-to-check-for-a-database-state-before-saving-new-records/34977871#34977871) .

Comment: what testing framework do you use?

Comment: using rspect but I used binding.pry() to examine the object and have not seen any properties with name error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use binding.pry you should first run

```
object.valid? # it will load it's errors, if any
```

and then you can see it's errors with

```
object.errors
```

Firstly, seed the test database with 5 `is_active` objects, then write the test:

```
it 'has error when creating sixth object' do
  obj = Model.new(name: 'Name', is_active: true)
  obj.valid?
  expect(obj.errors[:base]).to eq 'Cannot save more than 5 records'
end
```

Comment: is it established practices to run object.valid? before object.save before running .save?

Comment: yea, otherwise the errors would not be loaded and `obj.errors` will return nothing